# sqlite.interop dll not supported for windows 2008 r2 server in asp.net

Tags: c#, sqlite

I need to convert dataset into sqlite file. I have done this using mysql database and Sqlite.Interop.dll in my windows 8 PC running on 64 bit OS.

Now, I am moving the same code and running it on Windows server 2008 R2(64 bit) and Sqlite.Interop.dll file gives me an error.
" unable to load sqlite.interop.dll "
"could not find assembly sqlite"

Comment: well the `.interop.dll` just bridges the gap to your managed code - look in your development machine - you surely will find the missing sqlite.dll somwhere in your system directory (or where the path can find it) - but you should know that as you surely did install SQLite by yourself ;)

Comment: on my system those are called `winsqlite3.dlll` and the installer but 32bit and 64bit versions into `[Windows]/SysWOW64` and `[Windows]/System32` (sic!) - it should work if you grab the right one and put it right beside your program on your 2008 server